# A way to identify a record in Firebird without RDB$DB_KEY or a key

Tags: firebird

Is there a way to identify any record in any table without using **RDB$DB_KEY** or a table's key?

Unfortunately **RDB$DB_KEY** can only be guaranteed for the current transaction and might be different outside of it and without another key in the table one would not be able to uniquely identify a record if a record is an exact duplicate of another.

Comment: They said at current implementation RDB$DB_KEY of visible rows is persistent until database re-creation (restoring form backup). However there is no warranty it will always be so, it is implementation detail coming with no warranties. Even the data type may change as it is Firebird's internal "pointer" to the proper place on the disk. Making your app bound on this non-warranted "implementation detail" makes it subject to sudden and catastrophic crash in future with new Firebird versions. Also think about multi-server replication. Semantic-based "business domain" ID is better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than `RDB$DB_KEY`, a primary key, or a unique key, there is nothing else to uniquely identify a row.

It is possible to extend the lifetime of `RDB$DB_KEY` to the lifetime of a connection using DPB property `isc_dpb_dbkey_scope`. However, using that is a bad idea: it will start an internal transaction for the lifetime of your connection which will prevent garbage collection of old row versions. This can seriously affect the performance of your application.